# How to use tweetsharp.search?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm working with TweetSharp and I'm not able to use the "search" function.
I tried to find it  but in every example that I saw the second parameter is an integer and it doesn't work.

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, tokenSecret); 
            var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "stackoverflow" };
            XmlDocument xmlTwitterPost = new XmlDocument();

            xmlTwitterPost.Load(@"c:\socialShare.xml");
            xmlTwitterPost.LoadXml("<TableBox></TableBox>");

            foreach (var tweet in service.Search(options,)) 
            {..
}
```

I can't fin the way to insert the second parameter that is:

```
System.Action<TweetSharp.TwitterSearchResult,TweetSharp.TwitterResponse>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i used some of your code and created this sample that as far as i saw worked fine for me, i didn't put any action as second parameter and i got results

```
var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecrete);
        service.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecrete);
        var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "vucic" };

        var tweets = service.Search(options);

        foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Nemanja. I used the code above, as is. I only changed the tokens and the secrets. My code compiles and runs to the end, but the tweets variable is always null. What could I have done wrong or missed?

Comment: @codeshinobi
I just created console app and installed new tweetsharp and it worked.
At first i got stackOverflow exception for 'Q= vucic' but then i changed it to 'Q = VegaIt' and got 4 results.
After that i changed tokens to something invalid, and i didn't get excpetion during validation and loging, but my search returned null.

I'am not sure what is problem in your case but it defenetly worekd for me.

Comment: Thanks Nemanja. I got it to work. The tokens I was using were incorrect. I had to manually create them on Twitter instead of taking them from  OAuthRequestToken requestToken = twitterService.GetRequestToken();

Comment: Able to execute the API for fetching tweets just fine with your suggestion. Thanks Nemanja Malocic. However, when I try to do same with my keyword, for example "Health" it throws this error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'JSON integer 1526621325871222785 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'statuses[4].in_reply_to_user_id', line 1, position 19935.'" Have any suggestions for addressing this?