# Tweetsharp C# api is there any skip parameter?

Tags: c#, twitter

I've been googling everything without finding any answer. I'm using the function Search(), which doesnt seem to have any skip parameter.

I don't want to fetch every tweet from a specific hashtag at once.

Comment: Try it http://www.rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2010/02/04/Skip-Take-and-Twitter-Paging-Using-TweetSharp-To-Download-All-Tweets-from-the-Twitter-Timeline.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `count` parameter to the search options. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485129/808532):

```
var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecrete);
service.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecrete);
var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "vucic", count = 100 };

var tweets = service.Search(options);

foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
}
```

And checking the [source code](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/blob/master/src/TweetSharp/TwitterService.generated.cs) for TweetSharp we see the followng:

```
public class SearchOptions
{
    public string Q { get; set; }
    public TwitterGeoLocationSearch Geocode { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public TwitterSearchResultType? Resulttype { get; set; }
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    public long? SinceId { get; set; }
    public long? MaxId { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeEntities { get; set; }
    public string Callback { get; set; }
}
```

`SinceId` is wrapping the [Twitter 1.1 API since_id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets):

> since_id optional
>
> Returns results with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than)
>   the specified ID. There are limits to the number of Tweets which can
>   be accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occured since
>   the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.
>
> Example Values: 12345

So it looks to me that you'll need your code to remember the last id of the tweet returned, and pass the search with `SinceId` set to that value plus the count to create your 'skip' or pagination effect.

Just remember there might be gaps in the tweets returned based on timing, location, etc. from Twitter's end.